# .gitignore in Ubuntu is not applied

Tags: git, ubuntu

I am setting up a new repository and I have the following in the .gitignore file:

```
*.pro.user
*.o
```

However, when I do `git status` am seeing those ignored files listed. What is more, I am not able to add the `.gitignore` file in the repository, when I write : `git add .git/.gitignore` . How is this supposed to work?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The `.gitignore` file goes into your repository workspace (outside, and next to `.git/`), not into `.git/`.

Comment: Thank you both! I was looking for that for days!

Answer (score 4):

The `.gitignore` file does not go in the `.git/` directory.  Move it to your worktree root and it should work (and you'll be able to commit it there).